# Как узнать какое значение из словаря ближе всего к указанному значению?

Tags: python, функции, dict

Например, у меня есть словарь:

```
scores = {'player_1': 20, 'player_2': 16, 'player_3': 25, 'player_4': 20}
```

Как узнать какое из его значений ближе всего к 21?
Желательно сделать функцией

Comment: У вас два таких значения. Нужны оба?

Comment: нет, одно из них

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
def nearest(d):
    res = sorted(d.values(), key=lambda x: abs(21 - x))
    ans = res[0]
    return ans


scores = {'player_1': 20, 'player_2': 16, 'player_3': 25, 'player_4': 20}

print(nearest(scores))
```

Comment: Спасибо! Думал уже никто не ответит)

Comment: Не надо минимум сортировкой искать. Очень распространённый приём, но не эффективный.

Answer (score 4):

```
scores = {'player_1': 20, 'player_2': 16, 'player_3': 25, 'player_4': 20}
print(min(scores, key=lambda key:abs(scores[key]-21)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Добавлю еще вариант через сортировку. Таким образом будет первый еще и по алфавиту:

```
scores = {'player_1': 20, 'player_2': 16, 'player_3': 25, 'player_4': 20, 'a': 20}
print(sorted(scores, key=lambda k: (k, abs(scores[k] - 21)))[0])  # a
```

Comment: Это можно и без сортировки.

Comment: Да, у Danis отличный вариант.

Comment: Danis выдаёт ключ, а просили значение. А так, да - ответ отличный.

Answer (score 0):

Если совсем точно следовать постановке вопроса, то самое близкое **значение** отыскивается так:

```
@>>> scores = {'player_1': 20, 'player_2': 16, 'player_3': 25, 'player_4': 20}
@>>> print(min(scores.values(), key=lambda v: abs(v - 21)))
20
```